# Calculating integral of $x^4 \cos(x^{10})$ from $0$ to infinity by residue theorem

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculating integral of $x^4 \cos(x^{10})$ from $0$ to infinity by residue theorem.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty }x^{4}\cos x^{10} \; dx$$

Comment: Yes I know the answer is (pi)^(1/2) / (10*2^(1/2)).

Comment: I should use residue theorem. But there is no residue on complex plane.

Comment: I would change the variable to $x^{10}$ first. The answer then looks very plausible.

Comment: Can you help more? Do you mean x^10 = t ?

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit your attempts at answering the question into the question body.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ R>1 $, define a function $ f:z\mapsto\exp{\left(-z^{2}\right)} $, and consider a contour $ \mathscr{C}_{R} $ defined as follows : [image]

Applying the residue theorem to $ f $ over $ \mathscr{C}_{R} $, we get : $$ \oint_{\mathscr{C}_{R}}{f\left(z\right)\mathrm{d}z}=0 $$

Since : \begin{aligned}\oint_{\mathscr{C}_{R}}{f\left(z\right)\mathrm{d}z}&=\int_{\Gamma_{R}}{f\left(z\right)\mathrm{d}z}+\int_{\Delta_{R}}{f\left(z\right)\mathrm{d}z}+\int_{0}^{R}{f\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}x} \\ &=\mathrm{i} R\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}{f\left(R\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}\right)\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta}-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{0}^{R}{f\left(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{\pi}{4}}x\right)\mathrm{d}x}+\int_{0}^{R}{f\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}x}\\ \oint_{\mathscr{C}_{R}}{f\left(z\right)\mathrm{d}z}&=\mathrm{i} R\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}{f\left(R\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}\right)\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta}-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{0}^{R}{\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x}+\int_{0}^{R}{\mathrm{e}^{-x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x}\end{aligned}

And : \begin{aligned} \left|\mathrm{i} R\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}{f\left(R\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}\right)\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta}\right|\leq R\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}{\left|f\left(R\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}\right)\right|\mathrm{d}\theta}&=R\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}{\mathrm{e}^{-R^{2}\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}}\,\mathrm{d}\theta} \\ &\leq R\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}{\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{1+R^{2}\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}}}=\frac{R}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{1+R^{2}\cos{\theta}}}\\ &\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =\frac{R\arctan{\left(\frac{R^{2}-1}{\sqrt{R^{4}-1}}\right)}}{\sqrt{R^{4}-1}}\underset{R\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0\end{aligned}

Taking $ R $ to $ +\infty $, we get : $$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}{\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}x^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x}=\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}{\mathrm{e}^{-x^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x} $$

Which means : $$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}{\cos{\left(x^{2}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{2}} $$

Substituting $ \left\lbrace\begin{matrix}x=y^{5}\ \ \ \ \\ \mathrm{d}x=5y^{4}\,\mathrm{d}y\end{matrix}\right.$, we get : $$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}{y^{4}\cos{\left(y^{10}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}y}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{10\sqrt{2}} $$

Comment: Edit $$\int_0^{\infty } \cos \left(x^2\right) \, dx=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}}{2}$$ because the actual result is $\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}}{10}$

Comment: Yes you're right, I'll fix that.